# Samsung galaxy watch reminder app with notifications?

Tags: reminders

The standard samsung reminder app (simply called "reminder"), for some reason doesn't give notifications.

I haven't been able to find a good reminder app at all.

**Is there a good reminder app that gives notifications (i.e. vibrations) for the reminders?**

Note: I have a samsung galaxy watch 42mm.